# alternative for sscanf string with spaces in c?

Tags: c, string, parsing, proc

I am trying to retrieve information from /proc/cpuinfo file. 
I have retrieved number of cpu core using sscanf.

Now I am trying to retrieve model name similarly but I sscanf is not working this time because model name is a string including spaces.

Is there any alternative to retrieve it?

```
char *get_cpu_model()
{
   int fp;
   int r;
   char* match;
   char *cpu_model;

   /* Read the entire contents of /proc/cpuinfo into the buffer. */
   fp = open("/proc/cpuinfo",O_RDONLY);

    if (fp == -1) 
   {   
       printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
       return 0;
   } 
    while( r != EOF){

       r = ReadTextLine(fp, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    //    printf("%d %s\n", buffer_size, buffer);
       match = strstr (buffer, "model name");

       if (match !=NULL){
            /* Parse the line to extract the clock speed. */
            sscanf (match, "model name : %s", cpu_model);
            break;
       }
   }
   close(fp);

   return cpu_model;
}
```

The proc/cpuinfo file looks something like this:

```
processor:0
cpu core :1
model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
```

Comment: Maybe typo but did you tried to delete the space before the `:` in `sscanf (match, "model name : %s", cpu_model);˙`? Because there is no space in the given cpuinfo file.

Comment: you do "while( r != EOF)" while r is not intialized at the first loop

Comment: @Eraklon no, my file includes spaces and I checked that number of spaces does not matter

Comment: @bruno it does not give error but I will correct that. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Out of the fact you use *r* non initialized when you enter in the loop with an undefined behavior, it is difficult to find your problem without knowing the definition of *ReadTextLine*.

The other answer speak about some possibile problems.

Here is a proposal to do the work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * get_cpu()
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");
  char line[256];
  char * result = NULL;

  if (fp == NULL) {
    /* low probability to happen */
    perror("cannot read /proc/cpuinfo");
    return NULL;
  }

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    char * match = strstr(line, "model name");

    /* bypass ':' then possible spaces */
    if ((match != NULL) && ((match = strchr(match, ':')) != NULL)) {
      do
        match += 1;
      while (*match && isspace((unsigned char) *match));

      if (*match) {
        /* remove possible spaces including \r\n at end of line */
        char * pend = match + strlen(match);

        while (isspace((unsigned char) *--pend))
          *pend = 0;

        /* duplicate the string to not return an address in the stack */
        result = strdup(match);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  char * s = get_cpu();

  if (s != NULL) {
    printf("(first) cpu is '%s'\n", s);
    /* the result was allocated, free it when not needed anymore */
    free(s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
(first) cpu is 'ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

In my case the beginning of /proc/cpuinfos is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ head -2 /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

If you really want to have a function *ReadTextLine* it must do more than just a *fgets*, so let decide it also remove the spaces at the end of the line (it is useless to move spaces at the beginning of the line in this context)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * ReadTextLine(FILE * fp, char * line, int size)
{
  if (fgets(line, size, fp) == NULL)
    return NULL;

  /* remove possible spaces including \r\n at end of line */
  char * pend = line + strlen(line);

  while ((pend != line) && isspace((unsigned char) *--pend))
    *pend = 0;

  return line;
}

char * get_cpu()
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");
  char line[256];
  char * result = NULL;

  if (fp == NULL) {
    /* probably never happend under linux */
    perror("cannot read /proc/cpuinfo");
    return NULL;
  }

  while (ReadTextLine(fp, line, sizeof(line)) != NULL) {
    char * match = strstr(line, "model name");

    /* bypass ':' then possible spaces */
    if ((match != NULL) && ((match = strchr(match, ':')) != NULL)) {
      do
        match += 1;
      while (*match && isspace((unsigned char) *match));

      if (*match) {
        result = strdup(match);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: When `fopen` fails, it is never appropriate to write the error message to stdout, regardless of how unlikely you may believe it is to happen.  `if(fp == NULL) { perror("/proc/cpuinfo"); ...` writes a useful error message to the proper stream.

Comment: @WilliamPursell agree generally I use *stderr*, here I did not because the probability to not be able to open the file is very low, like already too many used stream. Anyway this is a good idea to (may be) learn something new to the OP, so I edit my answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your termination condition for the model name is "till the end of the line". Presumably `ReadTextLine` reads the entire line. So all you need is to find the beginning of the model name and `strcpy` it out of there:

```
match = strstr(buffer, "model name: ");
// ... match points to "model name: XXX"
if(match) {
    match += strlen("model name: ");
    // ... match points to "XXX"
    strcpy(cpu_model, match);
}
```

Note, however, that your code is using `cpu_model` without initializing it, which is a bug. You should either convert it to a parameter so that the caller would give you the buffer, or use `cpu_model = strdup(match)` to allocate the result on the heap.

As @bruno noted you're also using `r` before it's initialized. The correct condition would be:

```
while(ReadTextLine(fp, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) != EOF)
```

so that you exit immediately when you get `EOF` and don't need `r` at all.

Comment: what about to say him also *r* is compared with *EOF* before to be initialized when entering the loop, so the behavior is undefined

Answer (score 1):

`cpu_model` is never initialized so the line:

```
sscanf (match, "model name : %s", cpu_model);
```

doesn't have anywhere to store the data.  (That is, it is trying to write to wherever `cpu_model` is currently pointing, which is most likely not a valid memory location.)

The easiest fix would be to change the declaration to:

```
char cpu_model[128];
```

(and appropriately restrict the format string to be `%127s`)

Comment: oh yes, did not see that, congrat